# Eclipse Mars plugin installation - Rational Clearcase SCM Adapter - error

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I've downloaded and installed Eclipse Mars for DSL Developers including Xtext.
As I use Eclipse Kepler with the Rational Clearcase SCM Adapter (v.7.5.0), I've downloaded the newest Clearcase SCM Plugin (v.7.6.2) for Mars too.
Installation says :
"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found ... Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter 7.6.2.v201309301552 (com.rational.clearcase.feature.group 7.6.2.v201309301552 ..."

I checked the Size of the downloaded archive, everything's fine.
Do you have an idea?

Comment: I don't think that plugin is supported for Eclipse 4.X

Comment: Can you try the same installation in a 3.x Eclipse just for testing?

Comment: Tested with eclipse indigo 3.7 - works fine!

Comment: That is what I thought.

Comment: But Kepler 4.3 install works fine too :-/

Comment: Eclipse Mars is shipped with the newest Xtext version - if there is no way to use the plugin with mars - I would try to use the newest xtext with kepler

Comment: Is it possible to install the XText plugin (latest version) in a 4.3 Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, it is. So this would be the solution

Comment: What version of ClearCase are you using? You may have to try using the ClearTeam Explorer plugins or the open source one on sourceforge.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at the very least, I have managed to get past that message installing the 8.0.1.9 ClearTeam Explorer Eclipse plugin into Eclipse Mars.1 (64-bit) on Windows 7.

If you're using 8.0.1.x you should give the newer plugin a whirl.

Edit: The CTE plugin works, and since the ClearCase core is segregated to a ClearCase BackEnd process, it works with 64-bit Eclipse even though the ClearCase userspace is still 32 bit.

Comment: The ClearTeam Explorer Eclipse Plugin needs a CCRC WAN Server to work properly.

Comment: Odd, I'm connecting just fine to a local dynamic view using Eclipse Mars.1. I even created a fresh dynamic view on my local host. I'm using ClearCase 8.0.1.9. You may want to see if the eclipse-spawned ccbe.exe is allowed to connect the network...

Comment: Yes, connecting to ClearCase works fine - but only via the ClearTeamExplorer Perspective ("MyViews" shows my neccessary views). If I want to check out a file or show the version tree via the Java Perspective - I didn't see any option to do this. How do you connect to the dynamic view outside of the ClearTeam Explorer perspective?

Comment: Well, the first thing you need to do is import the project into the workspace from the dynamic view. The option appears to be File/Import/General/Existing projects into workspace. From there, you can use the "Team" context menu in the Java perspective to do the checkouts.

Comment: Got it, I imported the project (which is a new plugin for eclipse) via "Plug-In-Development" - now I used General -> "Existing Projects into Workspace" - works!

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to solve the problem (with the use of a ClearCase dynamic view)

- Update the XText version of Eclipse Kepler to XText 2.9 and install the ClearCase SCM Adapter (works with Kepler)
- Use Eclipse Mars (with XText 2.9), install the ClearTeam Explorer Plugin for Eclipse (can be provided by the ClearCase Admin in an offline CTE_Update_Site or it can be found in Windows../Program Files/IBM/IMShared)
  Then import the project via "Import - General - Existing Projects into Workspace"
  The connection to the ClearCase dynamic view is established automatically

Comment: Good feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

As commented, as possible workaround would be to:

- use a basic [Eclipse Kepler 4.3](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr) (instead of 4.4)
- install the [most recent XText plugin](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/download.html) on there.
- then install the [IBM ClearCase plugin for Eclipse](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256383)